# How to keep colums stable while dynamically altering the display value of rows in an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page with a drop down menu and a table. I have a Javascript function which will filter the table depending on the value selected from the drop down. I do this by traversing the table and changing the style of each row to either display:initial or display:none. The problem is that the columns change position when I select a value from the drop down and it's making my table look wonky. Does anyone know what might be causing this and how I can get around it? Any help would be much appreciated! I'm running it in Chrome if that is a factor.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<label for="filter">FILTER</label>

<select name="filter" id="filter" onchange="filter(value)">
  <option value="All">See All</option>
  <option value="Pending">See Pending</option>
  <option value="Approved">See Approved</option>
  <option value="Rejected">See Rejected</option>
</select>

<table id="reimTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
        <tr>
            <th>Pending</th>
            <th>$10.00</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Approved</th>
            <th>$2.50</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Rejected</th>
            <th>$23.59</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Resources.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the Javascript:

```
    function filter(value){
var table = document.getElementById("reimTable");
if (value == "All"){
    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        row.style.display = "initial";
    }
}
if (value == "Pending"){
    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        if (row.cells[0].innerHTML == "Pending"){
            row.style.display = "initial";
        } else {
            row.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
if (value == "Approved"){
    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        if (row.cells[0].innerHTML == "Approved"){
            row.style.display = "initial";
        } else {
            row.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
if (value == "Rejected"){
    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        if (row.cells[0].innerHTML == "Rejected"){
            row.style.display = "initial";
        } else {
            row.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Just use display = "" instead of display = "initial".  I think that will help.  I will admit that I don't really ever use "initial", so someone else might be able to explain it's actual purpose.  Whenever I want to toggle hide / show elements, I use "none" (for hide) and "" (for show)

Comment: what means *stable*?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set display to an empty string. I have modified your Resources.js file.

```
    function filter(value){
var table = document.getElementById("reimTable");
if (value == "All"){
    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        row.style.display = "";
    }
}
if (value == "Pending"){
    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        if (row.cells[0].innerHTML == "Pending"){
            row.style.display = "";
        } else {
            row.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
if (value == "Approved"){
    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        if (row.cells[0].innerHTML == "Approved"){
            row.style.display = "";
        } else {
            row.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
if (value == "Rejected"){
    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        if (row.cells[0].innerHTML == "Rejected"){
            row.style.display = "";
        } else {
            row.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use inline `on*` attributes, same as you don't use inline `style` attributes
- Use [**classList**.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to toggle a desires *utility* class.
- Use `data-*` attributes to relate elements to a dependency value instead of going up and down the DOM (like ie: `data-status="pending"`) directly on the TR element.
- Regarding CSS, hard to say what styles you have used so far.
- PS: Programming is not about copy-pasting code.

```js
const ELS_tr = document.querySelectorAll("#tableBody tr");
const EL_filter = document.querySelector("#filter")
const filter = (ev) => {
  const val = ev.currentTarget.value;  
  ELS_tr.forEach(EL => EL.classList.toggle("u-none", val && EL.dataset.status !== val));
}

EL_filter.addEventListener("change", filter);
```

```css
.u-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <label for="filter">FILTER</label>

  <select name="filter" id="filter">
    <option value="">See All</option>
    <option value="pending">See Pending</option>
    <option value="approved">See Approved</option>
    <option value="rejected">See Rejected</option>
  </select>

  <table id="reimTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
      <tr data-status="pending">
        <th>Pending</th>
        <th>$10.00</th>
      </tr>
      <tr data-status="approved">
        <th>Approved</th>
        <th>$2.50</th>
      </tr>
      <tr data-status="rejected">
        <th>Rejected</th>
        <th>$23.59</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

```
row.style.display = "table-row";
```

I think that setting it to an empty string would have worked just as well.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: You only need a classList.toggle - no need to reset to anything. The TR knows it's a table-row by default if you remove from it a class that was causing it to be `display: none;`